# Unity & C# // How can I change the physical material of the capsule collider to true or false as a Bool value in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game with Unity, but I'm having a small problem, can you help me?

How can I change the physical material of the capsule collider to true or false as a Bool value in C#?

I've created a physics material and applied it to my Player's Capsule Collider. In C#, I want to manually set true or false value through bool.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including a specific example of what you are attempting in your code and what isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What do you mean to a `bool`? You can assign one or `null` to `material` ...

Comment: @derHugo For example, I would like to know how to manually change the code in C# so that the Physic Material is False when the player touches the ground and True when the player jumps.

Comment: @OnePiece Do you want to disable the physics collider in runtime using script.

Comment: so `if (mybool) collider.material = mat1; else collider.material=mat2`?

Comment: As said - there is no (not even in the Inspector) setting for setting anything to `true` or `false` ... you either assign a `PhysicaMaterial` to `CapuleCollider.material` .. or not (`null`) ...

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the value of a boolean in your script when player is either touching the ground or not? OR Do you want to remove the material when players is jumping and re assign it when is grounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] PhysicMaterial materialToApply;
[SerializeField] CapsuleCollider colliderToAdjust;

void TogglePhysicsMaterial(bool Toggle)
{
    if (Toggle)
    {
        colliderToAdjust.material = materialToApply;
    }
    else
    {
        colliderToAdjust.material = null;
    }
}
```

As others have said, just set the material property to null when you don't want it, and assign it when you do. I saw you want to have it toggle on jump, so here is a quick and dirty way as an example:

```
void Update()
{
    if(colliderToAdjust.transform.position.y > 0
        && !colliderToAdjust.material)
    {
        TogglePhysicsMaterial(true);
    }
    else if(colliderToAdjust.transform.position.y <= 0
        && colliderToAdjust.material)
    {
        TogglePhysicsMaterial(false);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of (MUCH) better ways to handle jump detection (e.g. Raycasts) so please don't think this is a good method as it relies on the capsule being placed at 0 height and wouldn't work with an incline.